# How to put Names from my database into a JLIst that i have made in another class?

Tags: java

```
  public void GetUsersName(){

      try 
        {
            java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);

            java.sql.Statement s = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = s.executeQuery("SELECT Username FROM tblcustomers ORDER BY UserID");

            if(result != null){
                while (result.next())

                {


                    ListUserNames.usersJList.setListData(Username);
                    }




                }

            s.close();
            con.close();

        }  catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
```

Here my Code from the class where I make my JList Panel , which I then insert to another Class. I cans see my JScrollPane perfectly, the only problem is i can't insert the usernames into it, but I can see other values from a test array for example.

```
  public class ListUserNames extends JPanel{

    public static  JList<String> usersJList;



   public ListUserNames()
   {

      setLayout(new FlowLayout()) ;

      usersJList =new JList<String>(); 
      usersJList.setVisibleRowCount(10) ; 


      usersJList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION) ;

      // add a )Scroll Pane containing )List to frame 
      JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(usersJList);
      sp.setSize(300, 400);
      add(sp);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JList` has no mehtod to add or remove an elment once it's initialized. Instead you can use a `ListModel` with the `JList`.

Example:

```
public  class ListUserNames extends JPanel {

    public static DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

    public ListUserNames() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JList<String> usersJList = new JList<String>(listModel);

        usersJList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        // add a )Scroll Pane containing )List to frame
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(usersJList);
        sp.setSize(300, 400);
        add(sp);
    }
}
```

and your fetch method:

```
public void getUsersName() throws SQLException {
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
    JList<String> list = new JList<>();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Username FROM tblcustomers ORDER BY UserID");
    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    if (result != null) {
        while (result.next())

        {
            ListUserNames.listModel.addElement(result.getString("Username"));
        }

    }

    ps.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the static aceess to the list. ListUserNames.usersJList.setListData(Username);

That means "usersJList" might have not been initialized yet. 
In your can , it was not.

*2 solutions.*

**Solution 1**

> Initialize "usersJList" in ListUserNames.
>
> such as public static 
>   JList usersJList = new JList();
>
> This is not a recommended way

**Solution 2**

The second solution make a method to initialize userJList

Code:
GetUsersName.java

```
 public void GetUsersName(){
    /*-----your other codes----*/
        JList<String> usersJList  = ListUserNames.getUsersJList();
        if(result != null){
            while (result.next())
            {
                usersJList.setListData(Username);

             }

           }

    /*-----your other codes----*/
 }
```

ListUserNames.java

```
public class ListUserNames extends JPanel{

private static  JList<String> usersJList;

    public static JList<String> getUsersJList(){

         if (usersJList == null){
           usersJList =new JList<String>(); 
         }
         return usersJList;
    }


   public ListUserNames(){
       getUsersJList();

       setLayout(new FlowLayout()) ;

      usersJList.setVisibleRowCount(10) ; 
      usersJList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION) ;

      // add a )Scroll Pane containing )List to frame 
      JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(usersJList);
      sp.setSize(300, 400);
      add(sp);

    }
}
```